# Lift of an orientation-preserving homeomorphism evaluated on an integer

Tags: general-topology, analysis, dynamical-systems

I am reposting a misplaced question of mine from MathOverflow: I am an undergrad.

I am trying to solve the following:

We consider $S^{1}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, let $f:S^{1}\to S^{1}$ be an orientation-preserving circle homeomorphism and let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a lift of $f$. Show that $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\forall k\in\mathbb{Z},F^{n}(x+k)=F^{n}(x)+k$$

I have been indicated that this comes from the monodromy action of the projection $\pi$ on $S^{1}$ but as an undergraduate I have a very hard time working with this approach.
I have also been told to try to prove first that $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},F(x+1)=F(x)+1$$

for that I tried the following: we define $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to S^{1}$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\pi(x)=[x]$ with $[x]$ the representative of $x$ in $[0,1[$ for the congruence equivalence relation. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$,

\begin{align}
\pi\circ F(x+1)&=[F(x+1)]\\&=f([x+1])\\&=f([x])\\&=[F(x)]
\end{align}

from that we can deduce that $\exists l\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that, $F(x+1)-F(x)=l$. As $f$ is preserving the orientation we can also deduce that $F$ is increasing and thus $0\leq l$.

This is as far as I can get for now: next step would be to deduce that $l=1$ but I fail to see how to do that. As far as I understand the problem the general result should come by induction.

So if someone would kindly give me some hints to continue I would be very happy to read them.

Answer (score 0):

That $f$ is an orientation preserving homeomorphism should tell you that $F$ is *strictly* increasing, so $l > 0$. Now, by the intermediate value theorem, $F(x) = 1$ for some $x$ and we can choose $x \in (0, 1]$. If $x < 1$, this would contradict $f$ being a homeomorphism (why?).